# Assess statistical differences between groups

Tags: statistical-significance, group-differences, percentage

I have a list of percentages of words per group, something like:

```
         total_words nouns  verbs  swears  hate_words love_words ....
group1       321342   1.2%   1.4%    0.1%      0.2%       0.4%
group2       327492   1.5%   1.2%    0.3%      0.1%       0.3%
...
```

Given my problem, I can consider each dimension as independent, but I cannot assume that there should be any underlying statistical distribution for any of the variables. I would like to assess if the differences between groups on each dimension are statistically significant. What's the most appropriate test for this?

Bonus: As a tool to compute that I am using python, so kudos if you can provide some test that is already implemented in python, but I can work also with Excel (or other softwares).

Comment: You can use a chi-squared test on the actual numbers of each type of word, but be aware that you have so much data that even tiny differences are likely to suggest *statistical significance*

Comment: Do the columns represent disjoint categories or not?  For instance, are the `hate_words` also counted within the `nouns` and `verbs` columns?  It's essential to represent your data as *counts* of *disjoint* categories if you want to make progress.

Comment: thank you all. The columns are not disjoint, the analysis is though. For the purpose of my analysis I can easily discard very general columns (nouns, verbs) and check the correlation between groups on each dimension separately. Still, each dimension will not be completely disjoint one from each other.